# New added vector element is different then source

Tags: c++, vector, tuples

I've trying to use vector to store tuple elements:

```cpp
std::vector< std::tuple<size_t, void*, void*, void*> > t_elements;
```

I have a method that responsible for adding new elements to the vector:

```cpp
static void add_element(size_t el1, void* el2, void* el3, void* el4) {
    t_elements.push_back(std::make_tuple(el1, el2, el3, el4));
}
```

For some reason in some cases the new added element in the vector is initialized - the new added tuple fields are equals to zero. I perform a simple test just after I pushed the new element to see if it's happens:

```cpp
static void add_element(size_t el1, void* el2, void* el3, void* el4) {
    t_elements.push_back(std::make_tuple(el1, el2, el3, el4));
    if (std::get<0>(t_elements.back()) == 0) {
        std::cout << "Error!!! " << std::end
    }
}
```

In some cases I can see the error message. It's not stable, sometimes I see one error message, sometimes more then one and occasionally non.

This code is running as part of a class in test env, I simplified the code, run the same functions but in a clean env with one thread only, kind of "hello world". I don't see any errors in that case.

My question is what can cause this?

Comment: when `el1 == 0` then you print an error message even if the element was correctly pushed to the vector

Comment: anyhow, `push_back` is not broken, the bug is somewhere else in your code. Please try to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Hi. I forgot to mention, el1 is not equals to 0. I validate that also in my code. Thank you for the response. I just want to be clear I'm using vector and tuple correctly

Comment: are you accessing the vector from multiple threads maybe? Without any synchronization?

Comment: Could be. As I mentioned this code runs in a test env, There is at least two threads running.
I will further investigate and share my results. I've just want to make clear I used tuple and vector correctly, that it's not a problem in the code I shared.

Comment: try t_elements.emplace_back( el1, el2, el3, el4 )

Comment: what is "a test env" ? Why don't you know if the vector is used by more than 1 thread?

Comment: Hi. I do think it's some concurrent issue. If two threads try to add element "at the same time" to the same vector it's can explain this ?

Comment: @Ofir If one threads modifies the vector and another thread accesses it in any form without synchronization (e.g. a mutex) then that is a data race and the program has undefined behavior. This is true for all non-atomic objects, not only vectors.

Comment: Thank you. It’s approve my suspicious. I will take a further look at the code, maybe try to perform a simple sync using lock to verify it. I was worried I didn’t used vector/tuple correctly, but now I’m sure it’s not the reason for this problem I see.

Comment: After further looking at the code I saw that two threads accessing this vector.
I've used mutex in the critical sections and I don't see the strange behavior anymore.
Sometimes when you write quick and dirty code you miss important things...
Thank you for the help!